# Joomla 3.3 Article URL?

Tags: url, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.3 and have a lot of articles. My goal is to make it so the URL for an article is,

```
www.mysite.com/menu-item/article
```

However, right now when you click on an article it goes to

```
www.mysite.com/(id)-article
```

and takes you to the main page instead of staying on the menu item page. I'd like the page to stay on the menu item's page as I have page specific modules.

I'd like some explicit help as the answers when I Google are rather unclear.

Comment: You can't easily remove the article ID. You'd have to make menu items for each article. You can get the path you want by putting your articles in a category and creating a (optionally hidden) menu item to that category's blog layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a menu item for your article, as that will be used to create the url.

> …and takes you to the main page instead of staying on the menu item
>   page. I'd like the page to stay on the menu item's page as I have page
>   specific modules.

No, it doesn't take you to the main page (you can check that by looking at the URL in your browser) but because Joomla modules are assigned according to menu item IDs when there is no menu item Joomla uses the settings of the default page, your homepage, so you get the same modules as appear on the homepage.

The solution to both these problems is to create a menu item for the article (or at least to its parent category to fix module assignment).

There's a detailed description of the issues and how to deal with them in [How to control module display when linking to an article with no menu item](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item).

Comment: Do I need one menu item per article? I am displaying a list and will have numerous articles in the future.

Comment: If you care about removing the article ID, yes. To solve the module assignment issue, no, you only need a menu item for the parent category.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot Seth. Any chance you can give me a link or tell me the steps for this? I am sure it is elsewhere but during my search for this stuff I've found a lot of different things and it feels quite a bit confusing.